# How do I add basic user login screen for Spring Cloud Data Flow dashboard?

Tags: spring, authentication, cloud, dashboard

I have sample  Spring Cloud Data Flow dashboard application from [here](https://codenotfound.com/spring-batch-admin-example.html) and just like to add a simple basic login screen with user/pwd. How do I add it?

Comment: I have tried https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard. It doesn't work or login screen appears. Any other options?